# No Toolbar in OS X Lion

Tags: toolbar, hidden, osx-lion

since the lion update every toolbar is missing...

for example:

```
 - Word 2011
 - Adium
 - Finder
 - all
```

in Snow Leopard it was possible to click on an little button in right up corner. But its not visible.

In word 2011 i can make it visible with the CMD+ALT+T shortcurt. But the Button is already missing in every programm.

regards

Comment: You might find this question is better answered on superuser.com . Stackoverflow trys to focus on coding questions, not all question about computing.

Answer (score 0):

The function still exists, but is only accessible by right-clicking or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking on a blank bit of the toolbar (near where the button used to be in Snow Leopard) and then selecting `Hide Toolbar` from the menu that appears.